# I need a Tracking Pixel in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

In php i fire off my pixel in a if statement like this :

```
if ($result == C){
     echo "<img src='http://www.123123.com/tracking/RecordPixel.aspx?cmp=933&optional'/>";
  }else{
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL='http://123123.co.uk/index.php/'\"> ";
}
```

I am trying to do this in vb.net and i am looking for resources and cannot find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB.NET you can add a server control to your page, as a literal control. And in codebehind (for ex. in pageload), you can translate it in something similar to:

```
if (result = C) then
    yourLiteralID.text = "<img src..."
else
    yourLiteralID.text = "<meta..."
end if
```